# OpenShift support arbitrary user ids

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

From this reading on https://docs.openshift.org/latest/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines in the section **Support Arbitrary User IDs**.  It's recommended for:

- an image to support running an arbitrary user
- an image to make directories and files own by root group
- an image to declare `USER` with the user id, not the username

Example:

```
RUN chgrp -R 0 /some/directory && \
    chmod -R g=u /some/directory
RUN chmod g=u /etc/passwd
ENTRYPOINT [ "uid_entrypoint" ]
USER 1001
```

I'm not clear with what all these mean.

- Where is user 1001 defined?
- What does `g=u` mean?
- What does group `0` mean?
- I've specified in my image the below to create a new user and group, and run processes as that user (non-root).  Is this wrong?  Can someone please help explain and provide examples - what is the correct way of doing it?

  ```
  RUN useradd -M nonroot \
      && groupadd nonrootgr \
      && chown -R nonroot:nonrootgr /var/lib/myapp

  USER nonroot
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Where is user 1001 defined?**

You need to create a non root user account with that user ID.

See: https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-base-container/blob/master/core/Dockerfile#L71

**What does g=u mean?**

It sets the group permissions for the directory/file to the same as what the user has.

**What does group 0 mean?**

The `root` group has group ID of `0`.

**I've specified in my image the below....***

See the linked example above for how to add non root user.

You must use:

```
USER 1001
```

You cannot use an account name as value for `USER`, it must be an integer value.